# Problems with @Inject in Arquillian Test Java EE6

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, spring-data, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Arquillian for realizing integration tests in a Java EE6 Project.
I've created a shrink-wrap ear archive which is deployed on a web sphere 8 for Arquillian tests.
The archive has a beans.xml and a persistence.xml.

If i use EJBs inside the test via @EJB annotation, that works but if i try to inject a dao which is created by springData via CDI using @Inject i'm getting "could not inject members".

So don't really know what could go wrong now. A Persistence Context is also not injected and it was not possible to get an entity manager via jndi lookup. The Arquillian version is 1.7.

Seems a little bit strange. Maybe anyone has an idea what to try.

Thanks a lot everybody.

Comment: More info would be nice to help you (Code and pom.xml). Are you sure you're using the CDI part of Spring data and not the spring part ?

Comment: Yes, more info is needed.  If it comforts you, Arquillian is/was always very fragile for me, and it's pure luck to get it working with a non-standard setup (for example, Spring CDI in this case; I thought WebSphere uses Weld.)

Comment: Just a wild guess: If you use an ear, do you have a war in it that contains your test class? If so are you sure you put the beans.xml at the correct location? (Must be at WEB-INF/beans.xml not META-INF in a war!) Have seen this error so many times in the past.